# Adding sceneform(arcore) dependency in bazel

Tags: android, bazel, arcore, sceneform

I am woking on an android application which uses the bazel as a build system and in the app I want to add the sceneform dependency.Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

See [rules_jvm_external](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/) for managing your Android dependencies.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "3.0"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "62133c125bf4109dfd9d2af64830208356ce4ef8b165a6ef15bbff7460b35c3a"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.13.0",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com/",
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)
```

and use `@maven//:com_google_ar_sceneform_ux_sceneform_ux` as a dependency in your `android_binary` or `android_library` targets.